# How to reuse a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using some sample code I got from a tutorial to create basically a snapshot using AVCamRecorder. It doesn't save a picture, it just displays it in a little rect under the live camera view whenever I click a button. It seemed to be allocating more and more memory each time I clicked the button to update the image, so I put an `if (image) {[image release]}` and then continued with the rest of the code to capture the image. The problem I ran into there is that eventually I hit an EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I click the button fast enough repeatedly. I tried inserting an `if (image)` immediately before assigning it to my view, but I still get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tried adding an `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]` at the end, but that didn't help either. I still get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS after clicking the button several times. Is there a proper way to reuse this view? Thanks

```
if (image) {
    [image release];
    exifAttachments = nil;
}
[[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageDataSamplebuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
    if (exifAttachments) {
        // NSLog
    } else {
        // NSLog
    }
    NSData *imagedata = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    if (image) {
        self.capturedPicView.image = image;
    }
}];`
```

Comment: I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS at self.capturedPicView.image = image

Comment: Used a vote to salvage this from obscurity. Are you sure about the line you are getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Because that would indicate more likely a problem with your s'elf.capturedPicView' then it would with your 'image'

Comment: That's the line XCode points at. my capturedPicView is `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *capturedPicView;`

Comment: try image=nil after releasing it. If you don't set it to nil, "if (image)" will still return YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the image variable declared as __block? If not, you may get all sorts of weird things because you can't modify it within a block.

You probably don't need a separate image variable - just do:

```
self.capturedPicView.image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];
```

in your block.

P.S. And it looks like your original memory leak was due to not releasing the new image - you could have added autorelease to UIImage creation or just release it right after assigning (UIImageView.image retains it anyway):

```
image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
if (image) {
    self.capturedPicView.image = image;
    [image release];
}
```

Comment: I started getting null imageDataSampleBuffer sometimes, so I threw in an `if (imageDataSampleBuffer)` before assigning the image and it isn't crashing anymore. My NSLog of my exifAttachments is showing that sometimes there are no attachments, so I guess I just have to make sure `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` worked before doing anything with it. Thanks alot everyone.